# Should I use "kissed" or "kiss" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Should I use the simple past tense or the present tense?

> Would you mind very much if I ***kissed*** you?

> Would you mind very much if I ***kiss*** you?

Comment: I would imagine you'd make out just fine using either.

Comment: If you have to ask, I imagine you won't make out at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it should be:

> Would you mind very much **if I kissed** you?

It's a variant of:

> Would you mind very much **if I were to kiss** you?

But the other option:

> Would you mind very much **if I kiss** you?

Will be understood to mean the same thing, and the grammatical difference won't be noticed in the halfheartedness of the moment. It is, after all, speech, not formal written English.

Comment: I think the corollary to your "technically" point is that it could also be (again, more correctly) expressed as *"**Will** you mind if I **kiss** you."*

Comment: @Fumble: You're right. That works. And the sequence of tenses is correct.